# Redirecting user to new domain when he hit the old domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have made a sub-domain and moved my website from root to sub-domain now I want all the users to be redirected when they hit the old domain I have write some rules in my .htaccess file but those rules are not working here these are the rules I have been writing in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http://hkdcrandom.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.hkdcrandom.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Can anyone please help me find out what is it that I am doing wrong here would be a great help for me and saves my time as well.

**EDIT**

I have checked it again my rule is working but with a strange behaviour and that is when I hit the domain.

> http://hkdcrandom.com

It do nothing but when I hit with **www** like this

> http://www.hkdcrandom.com

it works fine and redirecting me back the exact URL that I want. Don't know why it is doing so as I have not given any **www** while writing my rule.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled? ;)

Comment: Yes mod_rewrite is enabled

Comment: `http://hkdcrandom.com` is not a host name.

Comment: It is when I hit this domain it shows me the website

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` header contains your domain name `example.com` or `www.example.com` and it doesn't contain url scheme so your  Condition will not match.

Change this line

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !http: //hkdcrandom.com$ [NC]
```

to

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !hkdcrandom.com$ [NC]
```

Comment: No sir it didn't help still the same issue.